# USBConnection nullPointerException

Tags: android, usb, usb-drive

I try to send command to my USB custom device. I think I set all properly - for example I can get ID of device, so Android "sees" it. However , when I try to send it command I get null pointer at line :

```
                     connection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointOut,send,send.length,SEND_TIMEOUT);
```

Endpoints are set correctly (I've checked it on log). This is my class. Please, help.

```
mTestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
                HashMap<String, UsbDevice> usbDevices = usbManager.getDeviceList();
                UsbDevice device;
                if (usbDevices != null) {
                    boolean keep = true;
                    for (Map.Entry<String, UsbDevice> entry : usbDevices.entrySet()) {
                        device = entry.getValue();
                        int deviceVID = device.getVendorId();
                        int devicePID = device.getProductId();
                        if (deviceVID != 0x1d6b || (devicePID != 0x0001 || devicePID != 0x0002 || devicePID != 0x0003)) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ID: " + device.getDeviceId()
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.e(TAG, "onCreate: " + device.getDeviceId());
                            UsbInterface usbInterface = null;
                            UsbEndpoint usbEndpointIn = null;
                            UsbEndpoint usbEndpointOut = null;
                            for (int i = 0; i < device.getInterfaceCount(); i++) {
                                usbInterface = device.getInterface(i);
                                //l("Interface[" + i + "] -> " + usbInterface);
                                if (usbInterface != null) {
                                    for (int j = 0; j < usbInterface.getEndpointCount(); j++) {
                                        UsbEndpoint usbEndpoint = usbInterface.getEndpoint(j);
                                        //l("Endpoint[" + j + "] -> " + usbEndpoint);
                                        if (usbEndpoint.getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                                            if (usbEndpoint.getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN) {
                                                //l("Found input!");
                                                usbEndpointIn = usbEndpoint;
                                            } else {
                                                //l("Found output!");
                                                usbEndpointOut = usbEndpoint;
                                            }
                                            if (usbEndpointIn != null && usbEndpointOut != null) {
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    if (usbEndpointIn != null && usbEndpointOut != null) {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    //l("Interface was null");
                                }
                            }
                            connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
                            connection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointOut, send, send.length, SEND_TIMEOUT);
                            keep = false;
                        } else {
                            {
                                connection = null;
                                device = null;
                            }
                            if (!keep)
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private static final byte[] send = new byte[]{
            (byte) 0xDA, (byte) 0xAD,  // const
            (byte) 0x02, (byte) 0x74, (byte) 0x00, // com
            (byte) 0xBF, (byte) 0xDB // last
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the loop which searches `usbEndpointIn` and `usbEndpointOut` might fail and then yields `null`. So, you should call `bulkTransfer` only if you have valid endpoints.

But the main thing is that you missed to claim the interface that you want to communicate with via `bulkTransfer`:

```
if (usbEndpointOut != null) {
    connection = usbManager.openDevice(device);
    if (connection != null) {
        if (connection.claimInterface(usbInterface, true) == true) {
            connection.bulkTransfer(usbEndpointOut, send, send.length, SEND_TIMEOUT);
            keep = false;
        }
    }
}
```